# $2\pi$ periodicity of discrete-time Fourier transform

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, continuous-signals, periodic

In my signals and systems course, we have learned that the discrete-time Fourier transform is $2\pi$ periodic, but the continuous-time Fourier transform is *not* periodic in general. For reference, we are using the following definitions of each transform:

Continuous-Time:

$$
x(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(j\omega) e^{j\omega t} \, d\omega \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ X(j\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) e^{-j\omega t} \, dt
$$

Discrete-Time:

$$
x[n] = \int_{\langle 2\pi \rangle} X(e^{j\omega}) e^{j\omega n} \, d\omega \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ X(e^{j\omega}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n] e^{-j\omega n}
$$

I'm searching for some intuition as for why the DTFT is periodic, but the CTFT is not. In class, my instructor presented the following argument: for a discrete-time signal,

$$
e^{j\omega n} = e^{j\omega(n + 2\pi)}
$$

and thus any $x[n]$ can be expressed as a sum of individually $2\pi$ periodic functions. However, I don't see why that argument only applies to discrete-time signals - I feel as if it also works for continuous-time signals.

Any someone explain?

Answer (score 9):

The argument does not work in continuous time. In discrete time the argument is that

$$e^{j\omega n}=e^{j(\omega+2\pi)n},\qquad n\in\mathbb{Z}\tag{1}$$

This is true because by definition $n$ is an integer. In continuous time we generally have

$$e^{j\omega t}\neq e^{j(\omega+2\pi)t},\qquad t\in\mathbb{R}\tag{2}$$

because $t$ is a real variable. Eq. $(2)$ only holds with equality for integer $t$, but not for all other values of $t$ (which would be necessary for $e^{j\omega t}$ to be $2\pi$-periodic).

But the fundamental reason why the DTFT is periodic is the fact that we deal with sequences, and if we assume that the sequence is the result of sampling a continuous-time signal, then it becomes obvious that different continuous-time signals can result in the same sampled sequence. E.g., take a continuous-time cosine

$$x(t)=\cos(2\pi f_0 t)\tag{3}$$

Now we sample $x(t)$ at instances $nT=n/f_s$, where $f_s$ is the sampling frequency:

$$x[n]=\cos(2\pi f_0 nT)=\cos(2\pi n f_0/f_s)\tag{4}$$

I leave it as an exercise to you to show that the frequencies $f_0=f_s-\Delta f$ and $f_0=f_s+\Delta f$ (with some $\Delta f>0$) result in the same sequence $x[n]$. This phenomenon is called [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). This means that frequencies above $f_s/2$ (also called the [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency)) cannot be distinguished from the corresponding frequencies below the Nyquist frequency. That's why the DTFT is periodic. There cannot be any new spectral information outside the frequency interval $[-f_s/2,f_s/2]$. If you haven't learned it yet, check out the [sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem), which will also help you understand the nature of spectra of discrete-time signals.

Also have a look at [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/29126/4298) to a related question.