# Why is the range of frequency for discrete time Fourier transform $-\pi<\omega<\pi$?

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, continuous-signals

In my class we are taught that the range for the frequency is $-\pi<\omega<\pi$ for discrete time Fourier transform, however for continuous time the limit is $-\infty<\omega<\infty$

why is this the case?

Comment: [This](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/29134/41790) should help.

Comment: Just in case, here is the link explicitly: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/29134/41790.

Answer (score 1):

Short intuitive explaination: In a time discrete system, the spectrum repeats itself at multiples of the sampling frequency (normalized sampling frequency is $2\pi$). Because of that, the limits of the fourier integral can be reduced from $\pm \infty$ to $\pm \pi$.